# How does DistanceFunction work with images in ClusteringComponents?

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis

Does anyone know the syntax to `DistanceFunction`? I am trying to define my own function to use with `ClusteringComponents`; e.g.,

```
ClusteringComponents[img, DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)]
```

Needless to say it does not work as shown (it overflows for some reason). I also tried using `ImageData@img` but that does not even terminate.

Comment: AT least in V8.0  `ClusteringComponents[]`doesn't seem to accept a custom `DistanceFunction`. Just those listed in the help

Answer (score 8):

I tested `ClusteringComponents` with the examples provided in the Documentation Center (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClusteringComponents.html) of `Mathematica`. In *Options > DistanceFunction* there is an example provided how to use your own `DistanceFunction` in `ClusteringComponents`:

```
ClusteringComponents[{{1, 2}, 3, {10, 11}, {12, {13}}, 14}, 2, 1, 
     DistanceFunction -> (Abs[Length[#1] - Length[#2]] &)]
```

I tried to apply this to an image without any success. I only ended up with some very strange looking error messages. After a few more tests I found the following solution. First of all, `ClusteringComponents` seems to work with a selfmade `DistanceFunction` only if you provide it with `ImageData` of a grayscale image. The following approach works:

```
Colorize@ClusteringComponents[ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "GrayScale"]], 3, 
  DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#1 - #2] &)]
```

[image] [image]